# Email is not sending pnpjs in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, pnp-js-core, send-email

I want to send mail to some users. But when i call send mail method, it shows no errors. but email not send.here is my code.

```
public emailProps: EmailProperties = {
                        To: ["abc@gmail.com"],
                        CC: ["def@gmail.com"],
                        Subject: "This email is about...",
                        Body: "Here is the body. <b>This is the test mail form SharePoint/b>",
                    };
public submit = () => {        
    sp.setup({
        spfxContext: this.props.context
    });

    return sp.utility.sendEmail(this.emailProps).then(rec => {
        console.log("Email Sent!", rec);
    },
    (ex) => {
          console.log("error: ", ex);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the error you are getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. I print in console log email sent. and it shows email sent.but user not getting any email

Comment: Are you sending an email to external users? Have you tried debugging where the execution goes? in success or error block of send email?? Also check the [Official documentation](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-SP.Utilities.Utility#sendemail).

Comment: yes i tried to send mail to external user. i included console log in success and error block. success block is called. you see my code. when click send mail button it shows in console log 'email sent !'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the below issue posted in GitHub, SharePoint REST API or PnP Core JS only sends an email to SharePoint site users NOT to external users.

[send email to external users PnP core js](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/issues/709#issuecomment-361835415).